# Modify an existing file watcher in webstorm 9?

Tags: webstorm

I have the default WebStorm file watcher running on our coffeescript files.  I can disable file watchers in the general settings section of WebStorm, but I can't find where I can modify the coffeescript watcher itself, to pass an extra parameter to it?

Comment: Screenshots please (whole settings window with title visible not just part of it) -- it's not clear at all why you cannot find "Edit" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Preferences/Tools/File Watchers` (or `Settings/Tools/File Watchers` if you are on Windows/Linux), select 'CoffeeScript' file watcher on the left, open it for editing, modify `Arguments` field accordingly